# Having error in helper method in wdio in async mode

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, wdio

Helper files that use other `browser` commands have to be moved to `before` hook.

````
NavigationByTextInSideMenu(page) {
    const sideMenu = {}
    await browser.waitUntil(async () => {
        await this.$$sideBarMenu.map(async (elem) => elem.isDisplayed()).length > 10;
    }, { timeout: 10000, timeoutMsg: 'Not all elements were visible' });
    await this.$$sideBarMenu.forEach(async (element) => {
        sideMenu[await element.getText()] = element;

    });
    console.log(Object.keys(sideMenu))
    await sideMenu[page].click();
} ```
````